# Firebase Security Rules UserPhoneId

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I created my app with the following database structure

```
Root/
  Users/
   +12345566777 
   +12345667765
   +43223456677
```

And here it is an example of my security rules

```
{ 
 "rules": {
      "$uid": {

       "Users": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
       }

}        
}

}
```

My problem is that instead of verifiying the auth.uid inside of my security rules i want to verify the (identifiant) the UserPhoneId is there any way to do that, thank you.

Comment: I think you should actually use the Firebase Auth UID as the key of the node rather than the phone number.  That string is guarantees to be unique among all users no matter what type of auth you use, and will not ever change for that user.

Comment: I know but now i can't change it, it's to late